# Edit Stripe embedded form

Tags: javascript, jquery, stripe-payments

I'm using the custom approach of the embedded checkout form for Stripe, on my website. I need to edit the form so the "Payment Info" button (when billing address is on), and the "Pay" button are of a different color. I tried adding some CSS rules on my style files using the ids and classes they use on their embedded form, and adding some css rules to the elements using jquery, but neither worked. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The embedded form is an iFrame thus you have no access to edit it via css or javascript. The Stripe documentation provides you some ways to edit items (like the text on the buttons), but the only thing you can really modify the css for is the button that opens the embedded form.

Comment: Thanks. In that case I'll have to use Stripe.js to make my own form. Do you know if Stripe has a template of their form (and validations) that I can use and customize on my website, using Stripe.js?